# How can one setup RAID 1 in Linux Mint 13?

Tags: linux-mint, software-raid, mdadm

I am trying to setup a Linux Mint 13 system using `mdadm`, with 2 1TB hard drives for a software mirror. I have tried following instructions found for Linux Mint 12, but the instructions fail to mention how to fix the `Cannot install GRUB to /dev/sda` error, even when I select the `/dev/md0` volume as where I wanted the boot loader in the Setup. Hardware RAID is **not** an option on this system

I finally decided to just install Linux to the first hard drive, and now I would like to setup the RAID from the hard drive that is currently working. Is this possible? If so, how?

I would appreciate step-by-step commands, as I'm more of a Windows/Mac user then a Linux user, but I do understand and check commands I learn from Linux before typing them

**EDIT**: The customer asked me to just install on one drive and he'll run a script to `dd` from that drive to the other as "backup"

Comment: I believe RAID is usually setup in the BIOS which shouldn't be affected be your OS.

Comment: @PeterMaxwell The customer specifically asked for a Software RAID setup

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=107460

Comment: @ekaj Tried, but it didn't work. No manual grub install was offered. The installation failed, and it looked as though it didn't keep the installation on `/dev/md0`

Comment: Do the drives have valid partition tables?

Comment: Yes. It's currently booted off of just one hard drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these directions [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=90878#p522997) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Currently trying the link, but could you please post the step-by-step instructions here as well in case their site ever goes down?

Comment: As a quick status update, looks like the array is "building" itself, which may have been why it stopped in the first place. Once it's done rebuilding, I'll add the FS to it and retry the installation

Comment: best of luck to you!

Comment: Got through the installation, but now I'm dropping down to a `BusyBox v1.18.5` system at the `(initramfs)` prompt, and I don't see any `dev/mdx` or `/dev/sdx` devices

Comment: Unable to verify; can't take back the bounty so I may as well award it